# How to make a variable plus a random number?

Tags: batch-file

Here's the little bit of code I have:

```
if %a%==1 set /a count=%count%+%random% %%100
```

What it does (at the moment) is simply stay as `%count%` and not increase by a random number between 1 and 100.

What I want it to do is this:
If `a` is equal to 1 (which it always is in an earlier line of code) it will increase count by a random number between 0 and 99. If anyone could help, that would be great! (It's my first time on stackoverflow and I'm new at programming so make it simple!)

Comment: Does the `set /a` line work if you use it without the `if`?

Comment: @RyanBemrose I just tried doing if %a%==1 goto set then had a seperate line with set /a on it but it still did not work. Thank you for the answer, but I'm still in need.

Comment: Is the posted code line paced inside an outer block of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem is? Have you posted your full script? The following script works for me.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set a=1
set count=0
echo count: %count%

if %a% == 1 set /a count=%count%+%random% %%100

echo count: %count%
```

As *MC ND* points out you may have problems if you're using `count` inside another block (e.g., inside a for-loop). The following does not work.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set a=1
set count=0

for /L %%x in (1,1,1) do (
    if %a% == 1 set /a count=%count%+%random% %%100

    rem This always prints 0!
    echo count: %count%
)
```

To get it working use `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`. The following is again working.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set a=1
set count=0

for /L %%x in (1,1,1) do (
    if !a! == 1 set /a count=!count!+%random% %%100

    rem Now this works!
    echo count: !count!
)
```